# Using Google Sign In to get authorization from user and then accessing user information from the PeopleAPI

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-people-api

in my android app I'm using [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) to allow users an option to log in along with other log in methods

When I present the sign in page, I can request for access to users date of birth, gender etc using Scopes. However i cant figure out how to actually access that data after the user gives their consent. I only can access email ID and name. But not things like date of birth and gender.

After the user signs in, I get an object of [GoogleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) type

I've searched online the advice seems to be to use the PeopleAPI but I cant find a clear link between the GoogleSignIn API that i'm using and the PeopleAPI - how do i "transfer" the authorization from the GoogleSignIn API to the PeopleAPI ? I want to let the People API know that my user has already consented

---

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google's [Authorization for Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android) for best practices to implement native authorization on Android. You can ask for relevant scopes for the user, and don't need to align with a sign in for the user.